# Sorting Table date Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, sorting, date, nstableview

I have a table with two columns: Date and Name.
I use this code to sorting elements:

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView

objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn
       row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {


NSDictionary *itemDictionary = [itemListArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];

if (aTableColumn == itemName) 
    return [itemDictionary valueForKey:@"ItemNameBrowser"];
else if (aTableColumn == dateCare)
{   
    NSDate *date_to_set;
    if ([[itemDictionary valueForKey:@"ItemdateCare"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; 
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; 
        [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; 

        date_to_set = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[itemDictionary valueForKey:@"ItemdateCare"]];
    }
    else
    {
        date_to_set = [itemDictionary valueForKey:@"ItemdateCare"];
    }

    return date_to_set;
}


else 

    return nil;

}



//sorting table view
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView sortDescriptorsDidChange: (NSArray *)oldDescriptors 
{   

[itemListArray sortUsingDescriptors: [tableView sortDescriptors]];
[tableView reloadData];

}

-(void)addItem {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; 
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];  



//Valori da aggiungere
NSString *newItemNameBrowser = @"Item";
NSString *newItemDateCare = [NSDate date];

NSMutableDictionary *newItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[newItem setValue:newItemNameBrowser forKey:@"ItemNameBrowser"];
[newItem setValue:newItemDateCare forKey:@"ItemdateCare"];

[itemListArray addObject:newItem];
[tableList reloadData];

[dateFormatter release];

}
```

In MainMenu.xib columns are:

```
Sort Key ItemName
Selector compare:
```

and

```
Sort Key ItemDate
Selector compare:
```

Columns Name is ok.
The problem is sorting date columns because don't reorder the date correctly.
Elements are considered only numbers.

[image]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are storing the dates in your `itemListArray` as string.  Don't.  Store them as NSDates, then they will appear sorted correctly.

You'll need to attach an NSDateFormatter to the NSTableColumn text field cell to convert them to a string for viewing.

Comment: I added my code. I use this: NSDate *newItemDate = [NSDate date]; to add element

Comment: As I said, store the dates as `NSDates`, not strings.  Only convert them to strings at the point where they need to be displayed and this can be done automatically with a `NSDateFormatter` on the text field cell.

Comment: I updated my code, now it work but don't use NSDateFormatterShortStyle. I want date with DD/MM/YYYY HH.MM.SS. I don't understand where mistaken. Can you help me? Thank a lot.

Comment: @Joannes: You are using medium style, not short style.  The date formatter you are using is the one you create in `table:objectValueForTableColumn:` not the one in `addItem:`

Comment: P: Right, I set NSDateFormatterShortStyle but "Central European Summer Time" remain. Can I delete it?

Comment: @Joannes:  if you are using one of the styles as opposed to an explicit format, the actual format is controlled by the computer's date and time settings (language and text formats tab in system preferences). The user has control of the format which is how it should be.